# Is there a way to reassign/change order of indices in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

If I understand it right, Accumulate Field node works in the order of indices.
Is there a way to reassign/change order of indices in Geometry Nodes or change the order of field accumulation?

Comment: The node `Accumulate Field` accumulates the passed values, and can even do this in groups. So it always depends only on the input. What exactly would be your goal? Can you describe it a little bit more?

Comment: Yes. But how do I setup which value is first, which value is second, which value is third etc It takes the order from the index either of points or vertices etc....      For example I have a random Distribution of points on faces on some surface. Let's say I want in one case to start my field accumulation from the left (i.e. from the smallest x values to the largest) in another case from the right (i.e. from the largest x values tp the lowest).

Comment: OK, I see. This is a bit complicated with the current tools. Unfortunately, there is no possibility of sorting (or loops), except via a self-created logic from nodes. And this is very individual, that's why I ask for a concrete example.

Comment: I think it`'s not possible right now dynamically. There is for example a kind of functionality in Blender Edit Mode -> Mesh -> Sort Elements ->. It's often used together with build modifier. It also has observable effect on Field Accumulation order. But dynamically seems to be impossible.

Comment: The example is exactly to have a kind of controlled brownian motion. I have particles distributed on a surface, I want to accumulate their position and build kind of lightning, but want to control with maybe empty and proximity control which particles coordinates are taken first for the accumulation.

Comment: Maybe this could be of some help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260218/sort-points-by-distance-from-object-expanded-sort-any-field

Comment: Thanks @jstkiko I already started myself thinking in similar direction. Maybe it ll work.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case (Accumulate Field) you can use the "Field at Index" node to change the order of accumulation.

Lets say we want to add up the X position values:
[image: Accumulate X position of vertices in index order]

We can change the order by inserting a "Field at Index" node. Here I'm using N-i to invert the index:
[image: Accumulate X position with an inverted index]