# How can I re-sort the points/indexes of an object in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wonder if there is a possibility to re-sort the indexes of a mesh according to a certain criterion?

Again and again in Geometry Nodes unfavorable situations arise where the point distribution or their indexes are in irregular order.

For example, I want to re-sort the points distributed on a grid with the node `Distribute Points on Faces` along a certain axis so that I can process them in order.

If I convert the distributed points for example with the node `Mesh Line` into a curve, a totally confused pattern comes out, because the indexes are distributed in a random order:

[image: Re-sort points - Screen 1]

However, I would like the indexes to be sorted and numbered from right to left so I can create a line along those points:

[image: Re-sort points - Screen 2]

**Bonus task:** The whole thing should at best also work with three-dimensional objects, because just a grid is sometimes pretty bland.

**PS**: I know there are *"hacky solutions"* out there, but that's what I really want to avoid and find a solid and as simple as possible logic based technique.

---

### Techniques comparison

Even though it's not a contest here, I'm providing an overview of the answers below.

Each approach is very different, but each also has its justification. How, when, which technique is best depends very much on the situation.

I have now combined and modified all five techniques in such a way that they are meaningfully comparable, and run according to the following criteria:

- All get as input any test value (float/integer)
- All process points in the point domain
- All provide the sorted index as result for further processing

[image]

*(Native Sorting, Quadratic Sorting, Resolution Sorting, Circular Sorting, Ramp Sorting)*

#### Features & Capabilities

|  | Native Sorting | Quadratic Sorting | Resolution Sorting | Circular Sorting | Ramp Sorting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Reliability | Perfect | Perfect (?) *(Review pending)* | Acceptable *(Depends on density & resolution settings)* | Bad *(at higher density)* | Acceptable *(Depends on density)* |
| Performance assessment | Perfect | Acceptable * | Good * *(Depends on resolution settings)* | Perfect *(if you don't care about missed points)* | Bad (!!!) |
| Can handle identical values | Yes | Yes | Yes, partially *(Depends on resolution settings)* | No | No |

**With a few points (below ~400), Quadratic Sorting is actually faster than Resolution Sorting. However, *Resolution Sorting* shows its strength with many values to be sorted and clearly outperforms Quadratic Sorting!*

*Note: I tried to make a comparison of the timings, but since the variants work too differently in the end and that depends on too many factors, it's not really possible to do that in a meaningful way.*

#### Advantages & Disadvantages

|  | Advantages | Disadvantages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Native Sorting | Captures all points, Best performance | - |
| Quadratic Sorting | Captures all points (?) *(Review pending)* | Average performance |
| Resolution Sorting | Performance depends on adjustable resolution | Performance/Reliability depends on adjustable resolution Has a small error rate at high density |
| Circular Sorting | Is ultra-fast * | "Swallows" points very easily at higher density |
| Ramp Sorting | - | Is computationally intensive at high density Does not work reliably at high density |

**The "Circular Sorting Technique" is so fast mainly because at high density the more points are discarded and thus no real comparison to other methods can be made!*

#### Use cases

- If you set a high value on precision and no point should be lost: **Native Sorting**
- If you set a high value on precision and you have less then ~5000 (?) Points: **Quadtratic Sorting**
- If you need a good result, but can live with a small error rate: **Resolution Sorting**
- If you need it really fast, and if you don't care about precise detection: **Circular Sorting**
- If you are totally crazy and feel like experimenting: **Ramp Sorting**

### Download the comparison and try it yourself

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+, all methods except "Native Sorting")*</sub>

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+, all five methods)*</sub>

*These files are all adapted for use on point clouds (!)*

Comment: nice comparison, though circular sorting doesn't get much slower because it just diregards more and more points. For my test of 5000 points, 4585 (91.7%) remained unsorted: https://i.imgur.com/9reNsbg.gif - so it's like taking my solution, removing 91.7% points, and then sorting 500 points instead of 5000 points. Still, it's a problem in itself to figure which points to remove, so I might actually use the Circular Sorting in the future... Also consider this: `$\bbox[red, 5px]{\color{white}{\mathbf{NO}}}$` ([color table](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10116/43517))

Comment: @quellenform if it wouldn't take to much of your time, could you update the question with "resolution based sorting". I would like to see how it compares to other methods. :)

Comment: @jstkiko ...Thanks for your contribution, I'll do that of course!

Comment: Nice update! However I find resolution sorting definitely more performant than quadratic sorting.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ...ups, that was indeed a typo! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for this great Q&A. I can't seem to figure out how to use these though, could someone point out what I'm doing wrong in this setup, for ex: https://i.imgur.com/TDa1FpN.png ? I expect a new order that goes from left to right, but I get this seemingly random one instead. I get the same order from all other method node groups as well so obviously I'm messing something up. Thanks! ([File](https://blend-exchange.com/b/pynKlgN1))

Comment: @Kuboå This setup is NOT a reorganization of the points, but only a mapping of the indices. Have a look at the file with the comparisons. There you see, for example, that in the group *"_Visualize"* I transfer these mapped indices with `Sample Index` to the positions of a line. So the sorted index only says which point should put at this index, and it depends on you what you do with this information. Does this make more sense to you?

Comment: @quellenform Yes that makes sense, thank you. Although I can follow and recreate the sampling position example just fine, I still got stumped with my scenario above, however. I think if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong [trying to create a selection for the left-most point by (the now sorted) index here](https://i.imgur.com/oSyL8DD.png), it'll finally click.

Comment: @Kuboå So you want to know which point is on the far left? After sorting, the lowest value is the point with the index $15$, which is why it is assigned to point $0$. therefore you have to use `Sample Index` to fetch the sorted value, and make a comparison with the current index of the points. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8TQ3.png

Comment: @quellenform Yeah that makes it clear, thank you very much.

Comment: @Kuboå You are welcome! If the solution "Native Sorting" helped you, please consider an upvote below. ;-) Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## "Native Sorting Technique"

### Blender 3.4+

In version 3.4 there is an interesting new node, which allows a native sorting of the points of a curve based on a weighting.

The node is called [Points of Curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/topology/points_of_curve.html#index-0), and returns the index of a specific point of the curve depending on the value passed.

To achieve sorting with this, first the point cloud is converted into a curve, and the sorting criterion is used as *Weights* for `Points of Curve`.

Basically all possible sorting can be done in this way:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

---

#### Examples

- Here you can find an example of use (in which, funnily enough, exactly the opposite should be generated, namely a jumble of the indices): [How to randomize/shuffle indices in *Distribute Points on Volume*?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283169/145249)
- And here is a nice practical example that uses a texture map as a sorting criterion (thanks to *@RobinBetts* for this creative idea!):
  [Sorting Indices of points circularly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/287583/145249)

As you can see: Only the value that is passed as sort criterion is decisive.

### Blender 4.0+

The concept of weighting has been used in some other nodes since version 4.0, and [Points to Curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/points_to_curves.html) is available here with precisely this feature.

This converts points into curves and uses the weighting as a criterion for the order of the points to be used.

As a result, a curve is obtained whose points are arranged exactly according to the value of the weighting.

This curve can then be converted back into points if necessary.

[image]

Comment: This is great news! I'll wait for the stable version as usual, and I would hope we would just get a general sorting field already…

Comment: In Blender 4.0.0 beta a new node `Points to Curves` is available by which the points can be sorted directly (if the original index is needed afterwards use `Capture Attribute`can be used). See also: [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/304665/139016)

Comment: @Patter Thanks for the tip! ...I noticed it almost at the same time and updated the answer ;-)

Answer (score 14):

## "Circular Sorting Technique"

[image]

### How does this work?

Roughly speaking, I assign a range of the value to be sorted to a range from $0$ to $\pi$, which results in the distribution of points on a semicircle.

On the resulting shape, I apply a mesh trick that gives me a curve with ordered points.

This may sound rather muddled now, but it is really quite easy to understand if you represent it with pictures...

For example, if you distribute points on a grid with the node `Distribute Points on Faces`, and display the value of the *X-axis* on a semicircle, it looks like this:

[image]

If you now create a convex hull from the points on the semicircle and convert them back into curves, you get nicely sorted points. This works basically with arbitrary values.

Here you can see an example of sorting along the *X-axis* and along the *Y-axis*:

[image]

[image]

And this is how it looks, for example, with a grid rotating on the *Z-axis*:

[image]

---

### Step by step to the solution

1. First of all, you define by which value you want to sort. In this example I use the *X-axis* and separate it from the single points.

   [image]
2. Next I use the node `Attribute Statistics` to determine the lowest and the highest value, which serves as input range for the node `Map Range`.

   I then map the values used here to a semicircle, so that the previously captured value of the *X-axis* is distributed along this semicircle.

   [image]
3. Then I create a line with the node `Mesh Line`, whose subdivision corresponds to the number of the original points, and set their positions to the previously created positions on the semicircle.

   I achieve this by simply rotating a vector with the previously obtained angle.

   [image]
4. And now comes the crucial step: I first capture the index of each point, so that I can later determine the original index, and then I use the nodes `Convex Hull` and `Mesh to Curve`.

   The ingenious thing about this is that `Convex Hull` forms a mesh hull around the points previously distributed on the semicircle, but this does not yet lead to the goal.

   Only by using the node `Mesh to Curve`, this mesh is transformed into a curve, whose indexes are ordered continuously from left to right.

   Since the original index was previously captured with the node `Capture Attribute`, a connection between the new ordered indexes and the original indexes can be established with `Transfer Attribute`.

   [image]
5. With the help of this index now arbitrary values can be fetched and used in another mesh/object with the node `Transfer Attribute`.

   [image]

---

### Download the file and try it yourself

[image]

> **Important Notes:**
> Since this technique is based on the node `Convex Hull`, but this ignores distances between vertices below a certain value and combines the points arbitrarily, this technique may lead to unexpected results.
>
> For less densely distributed points it works great, but as soon as the vertices are very close to each other along the sort (or even identical), they are ignored.
>
> in this particular case: if the points on the circle are distributed with an angle of less than $0.01°$, they will not be recognized. *(Thanks to @Robin Betts for the attentive reading)*.

### Q & A

**Q:** It does not work at all with my mesh! Why?
**A:** Since this technique counts the points in the domain *Points* with the node `Domain Size`, and a mesh returns *Vertices* and is not a *Point Cloud*, you have two options:

- Either you apply the node `Mesh to Points` before, which converts your mesh to points.
- Or you switch the contained node `Domain Size` from *Points* to *Mesh*.

**Q:** Why actually a semicircle and not a whole circle?
**A:** Because the numbering is finally done by converting the convex hull into a curve with the node `Mesh to Curve`, which uses the longest edge as a reference point for the first vertex.

Comment: Hi, Q! I really want this to work. (I once posted a solution very similar to this, and deleted it, because I found that without too much difficulty, I could [kick it into failing](https://pasteall.org/blend/29cec4281ba64f36bfd854d62c92ee95) ). _Convex Hull_ has a nasty habit of deciding to merge vertices, where it doesn't think it needs the resolution. I wonder if there's a way to space out samples, interleaving dummy concave edges, or something, to improve this from convex-hull accuracy (not so great)  to floating-point accuracy, (which is the unavoidable limit)?

Comment: As always - a really nice solution :-)   -  Another approach for sorting is described by @JstKiko in the thread [Sort points by distance from object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260218/sort-points-by-distance-from-object-expanded-sort-any-field).

Comment: @RobinBetts Damn, you are right! If the difference of the angles is lower than $0.01°$, then the node `Convex Hull` simply skips the point. I would hate to delete this answer though, it was a lot of work and I still think it might help some ...what do you think? I will definitely add the hint though.

Comment: +2 (q+a) that's amazing!!

Comment: @quellenform Oh, _definitely_ not looking for deletion! Just interested in whether any of us can come up with an improvement.. The other solution you've been pointed at has a similar limitation. There might be some way of spreading samples evenly? That could be another Q.

Comment: @RobinBetts Haha, this is catch-22: actually, you can only distribute something evenly if you also have continuous indexes, right? ;-)

Comment: @quellenform That's what I've been trying to get around :D

Comment: @quellenform Maybe I misunderstood something - but on windows 11 with blender 3.1.0 I don't lose any vertices even with 0.001 degree and a radius of 0.001 with this setup: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=1VzsYz4R" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1VzsYz4R/). Only if I set the angle to 0, so that points are exactly the same, they will be skipped. - So, how can I reproduce the skipping behaviour of the Convex Hull node?

Comment: @AndréZmuda This is because the input field requires a value in degrees, but when you feed the input with a value from another node, it must be in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian)! I know it's really confusing sometimes, but that's why it worked for you ;-)

Comment: For testing float accuracy, you might find this snippet useful (paste it into Python console): `import numpy as np; start = 1; f"{np.nextafter(np.float16(start), np.float16(inf))-start:.10f}"` - it displays the smallest possible step in float16 that Blender uses. For start = 1 it's about 0.001, but for start = 10 it's significantly bigger at `0.0078125`, and for start = 0 it's only `0.000000059604644775390625` (`5.96...e-08`)

Comment: @quellenform Yes, you are right, I missed that. When I change the step to 1/10000 (rad) which is about 0.0057°, I can reproduce it.

Comment: Actually it's float32 not float16, Blender does use float16 in some places, but in geonodes it uses float32, so the actual numbers for start = 0, 1, 10 are roughly `1.4e-45`, `1.19e-07`, `9.54e-07` quite more precision.

Comment: @AndréZmuda By the way, there is a math node that includes the "to Radians" option.

Comment: @quellenform Good to know, this reduces my brainload ;-)

Answer (score 8):

### Quadratic Sort (Pre B3.4)

This is one of outdated answers that would unnecessarily bury (currently) objectively the best [answer by quellenform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277587/60486). You can still access this answer by reading the [previous revision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/264967/3).

Comment: I like this solution. It's compact and seems to be robust.

Comment: @AndréZmuda I think it's 100% perfect. The only topology where it would fail, that I can think of, is one with over 16777216 vertices, when the float smallest increment goes over `1`, and yet I position the vertices at +1 increments for each index. Of course there could be more failure points like inaccuracies of some nodes used (recently I got bitten by the color ramp reducing precision severly), but since I'm not moving vertices, only counting, it probably works for any practical geometry...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Could you please also give this ingenious node tree a proper name? I'll test a bit more, make a few comparisons, write an overview and then add that to the question.

Comment: Sort Perfect 3000

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady OK, ...then I will choose "Quadratic Sorting Technique" ...? ;-)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ...I pulled back the Accepted Answer because I want to start a Bounty on it (which I can start in 5 hours). ...the answer is simply brilliant!

Comment: I learned Accumulate Field from you and array technique from @AndréZmuda :D

Comment: MVB: This looks definitive, until loops or somesuch available? Curious: (n^2) time if serial.. but this looks susceptible to parallel processing? Are GN fields intended to be put through the GPU, eventually?

Comment: @RobinBetts Loops are available, just not `while` loops - iterating over geometry is an equivalent of `for v in geo.vertices`, and what I'm doing here is `for i in verts: for j in verts` or rather `x2=x*len(x); for v in x2`. Parallel may improve the speed but not complexity... And I would expect that Blender eventually will introduce *Sorted Field* node... But then it would be nice to have some sequence bigger than Vector to sort by more than 3 criteria...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Only, that these for loops have some major limitations, that make life so hard: You can only change the item, that you hold in your hand; you can only see the state of your geometry before starting the loop, which makes the Accumulate Field node necessary. - Oh, I forgot - you may as well create geometry at the point, that you hold in your hand, when using the Instance on Point "loop". - We would already have much more possibilities, if we had not these limitations ;-)

Comment: Thanks @quellenform !

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Have you actually tried using the original ID as the search criteria instead of the *X-axis*? I'm creating a new comparison and testing this right now, and it doesn't work well for me. Do you have any idea why or can you reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @quellenform I sort by x coordinate, then index. Do you mean to sort by ID, then index? Wouldn't the original ID be the index? Oh and if you know your ID is unique, you can sort by a single criterion...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I am about to post the following test example: https://blend-exchange.com/b/MMpp7vv1/ ...Tests 2, 4, and 5 fail on *Quadratic Sorting*, and I just can't find the problem. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @quellenform hmmm... What's the logic there with the accumulate field in tests 2 and 4? For example, if there's X coordinates: 1, 2, -100, 4, 5, the *Leading* values will be 1, 3, -97, -93, -88, and so the vertices will be sorted as 3, 4, 0, 1, 2. I just don't see a reason for combining Accumulate Field and sorting like that... As for ID, you're casting very large/very small integers to float32. See my first comment here about number `16777216`- though in this case it's not a downside of the setup - you can duplicate the setup, where TA nodes use integers and it should work for an integer key.

Comment: @quellenform I haven't figured out the "what is supposed to happen" part, but I think the problem comes from the Accumulate node being recalculated - so you need to use a capture attribute after it, and before the sorting algorithm, to make sure it's evaluated once, and the sorting algorithm doesn't interfere with Accumulate Field... BTW, an impressive project, inspires me to make a big comparison like that too, though you butchered my pretty node tree :D

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady The node `Accumulate Field` was only meant as a test to get other values for the sorting, otherwise it has no deeper reason. The real question is: Why is the result so different compared to the other variants? However, your tip helped, the node `Capture Attribute` solved it (even if I currently can't quite figure out why). And hey, there's nothing "butchered" at all, just made them looking a w e s o m e! ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136849/discussion-between-quellenform-and-markus-von-broady).

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Could you find the error in the meantime? Is it my implementation or your nodes?

Answer (score 5):

### Resolution based sorting (pre B3.4)

This is one of outdated answers that would unnecessarily bury (currently) objectively the best [answer by quellenform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277587/60486). You can still access this answer by reading the [previous revision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/265103/1).

Comment: Great, thanks (also to @jstkiko) for the contribution! A few more days and we have all the relevant variants of the sorting options together in one thread ;-)

Comment: I think this could be possibly optimized: read the stack size as early as possible to remove the excess geometry first; or maybe create multiple mesh line geometries going from 0;0;0 to 0;0;0 and having vert counts of 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 or vert counts of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, and then joining them as instances and instancing them on the "high res mesh line" taking log10/log2 of the stack size as instance index. The main sampling line now could have much less resolution, as verts would be added on demand...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thank you for summarizing and improving my solution. I was offline for a couple of days so I couldn't post it myself.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I have built a node, that calculates the minimum delta of an attribute. This way, you could know, which resolution you need. The only drawback is it's complexity: O(n²). Originally I intended to integrate it into the solution of JstKiko. But I didn't because of this drawback. Here you may take a look at it: [min_delta_attribute.blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/wGROdpwS/)

Comment: ... and it crashes on my computer with a high number of vertices due to the grid. Maybe because I currently only have onboard graphics. If you experience the same: This could be resolved by replacing the grid with instances of meshlines and adapting the solution to it.

Comment: @AndréZmuda right, you can duplicate the geometry for each vertex, and for each such geometry remove the vertex for which you duplicated it - this way you can look at the nearest vertex that isn't self... Which is quadratic. But since my other solution has perfect accuracy with the same complexity, this defeats the purpose. Spawning the vertices on demand as I described in the above comment is also less than O(n²) but it still doesn't solve resolution problem. But I think I have an idea for a faster way to find smallest delta...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I had the idea to group the points into chunks and thus reducing from n² to m*k² with m<<n and k<<n. But I couldn't find a way to do this with GN till now. - To be more precise: I could build those chunks, but I didn't find a way to compute the deltas for these chunks, then.

Comment: @AndréZmuda I figured if you spawn a mesh line setting the value to Z, and setting XY = 0, you can now instance triangles on these points and use ray casting down and up with a slight offset (shouldn't be too hard to calculate the smallest possible offset at a given float, basically reproducing `nextafter()` in nodes) and so you can find the next/previous point. Still doesn't help with sorting, though. I'm thinking, in case of snapping the values to integers, you could also capture attribute of how much you snapped and use that as 2nd sort criterion (index becoming the 3rd).

Answer (score 3):

### "Ramp Sorting Technique"

This is one of the outdated answers that would unnecessarily bury the (currently) objectively best [answer from quellenform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277587/60486). You can still access this answer by reading the [previous revision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/264975/3).

Comment: Since you're comparing, here's a dare: test all 3 solutions on Suzanne with 4 subdivision levels. :D

Comment: I tested this without subdivision and got ~1.7 seconds, so I didn't dare to try subdivisions. The Convex Hull answer was blazing fast and was dealing even with 4 subdivision levels. Though when I decided to randomize on X a little by applying subdiv and using proportional editing - it crashed (probably even unrelated to your setup :D). My solution was very fast without subdivisions, scaled very well to one subdivision but at lvl 2 crashed :D. Though when I resign from edges (> to points > to verts) it survives lvl 2 and takes 3 seconds...