# How to duplicate geometry-node instances and re-seed those generated instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

**Important:** This is a simplified version of the node tree I have to help better visualize my question.

I have a `collection` node consisting of cubes, cylinders and spheres that I randomize as instances on a grid. I duplicate this layer with a `translate instances`, so that two layers are created, of which I place one lower on the Z-axis (see images below).

[image]

[image]

I would like the instances on the bottom layer to be re-seeded, so that the instances are not in the same way ordered as in the top layer. I could duplicate the whole first layer and then re-seed on-top of both, but then the computing power of my actual node tree would become too heavy. Is there a way to re-seed the instances of the bottom layer ***after*** the `instance on points` node of my node tree?

Comment: No, it does not work like that. On the geometry you created (which I know by now), no change of this kind is possible afterwards. Instances are copies, and you have no possibility to change the seed values afterwards. You could at most rearrange the instances, which is not optimal, but it might work: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265202/

Comment: @RPaladin Regarding your great rephrasing: there exists a subtle difference between "seed" and "set" ;-)

Comment: @quellenform Thanks a lot :) With the link you give me you actually say: yes it is possible! :) This solution works for me, with some small changes. Do I have to answer my own question with the result or is your reference to the link enough to answer this question?

Comment: @RPaladin Thanks voor your rephrasing. My English is not so good, so if this helps people.... :)

Comment: @EwSa could you post a short answer explaining the solution to the problem you found in the answer section below? Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

The following link provided guidance for re-seeding the duplicated instances: [blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265202](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265202/). I chose Robin Betts' solution, since this was for me a quick solution and not all the instances had to be moved to a different place. Hulifier's solution is of course also possible.

In this solution the geometry is separated, after which half of the instances are shuffled by the seed of a `random value` node. After this the geometry is merged again. All this happens in a group called the Shuffle index.

[image]

The Shuffle index group is then used in the following node tree to shuffle the instances of the bottom layer. The shuffle index is placed three times in a row to get a reasonable shuffle.

[image]

Result:

[image]