How to randomize the index of instances and preserve the instances for each seed
I want to change the seed for the random value but preserve the instances for each seed


so you want all instances once, but random, right?

Do you mean randomize the order of the instances?

Yes, it's like you changing the arrange of the instances,

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267179/how-to-shuffle-an-attribute-in-geometry-node

May I recommend to apply this : What should I do when someone answers my question?

you can use this node setup:

I create a mesh line with the number of instances, save their index to idx, give them a random z-value and sort a curve by these z-values. Then i can read out the stored idx value to give them their instance indices.

Hope it helps.
Happy geonoding!
