# Randomize instances WITHOUT repetition?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, random

Hello Blender community!

I'm trying to generate random positions for a set of objects. I've got 3 objects (cone, cylinder, cube) with a variable of 3 colors (blue, red, yellow), which makes 3x3=9 objects to randomly arrange. The idea is to make the NINE DIFERENTS OBJECTS to appear with a RANDOMIZED POSITION.
I used an Instance on Points node with a Collection Info that links to a collection containing my nine objects. I added a Random Value to link it to the Instance Index of the Instance on Points node.

Here's the problem: no matter what data I enter, it seems impossible to randomly generate a grid containing all 9 objects at the same time. Even with the Random Value seed, there's always one, two or three objects that repeat (see attached photo).

[image]

Does anyone have a solution ? Or is there none?
Thanks a million!

Comment: Well, *Random Value* generates random values, but this does not mean that they are not repeated. What may help you here is to shuffle the indices before instantiation. ...like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283165/geometry-nodes-how-to-randomize-shuffle-indices-in-distribute-points-on-volume/

Comment: Thank you for your answer @quellenform ! You’re right ! I’ve found this thread before posting my question, but as a geometry nodes novice I gave up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously answered here:
[Geometry Nodes: How to randomize/shuffle indices in 'Distribute Points on Volume'?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/303062/16008)

For clarity here is purely **Geometry Nodes** solution for your case.

[image]

Remove half randomly selected points and add them again.
This will shuffle the indexes and you can play with the **Random Value** node **Seed** parameter to get a variant you like.

Comment: That's brilliant and it works PERFECTLY ! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found a solution but using a script thanks to the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2Q6tKUz-PM

Here's the script:

```
import bpy
from copy import copy 
from random import shuffle

objSources = bpy.context.selected_objects
objTargetsTransform = [[copy(objSource.location), copy(objSource.rotation_euler)] for objSource in objSources]
shuffle (objTargetsTransform)

for objSource, objTargetTransform in zip(objSources, objTargetsTransform) :
    objSource.location = objTargetTransform [0]
    objSource.rotation_euler = objTargetTransform [1]
```

It works great! (see attached photo)

[image]

Otherwise, I'm sure it can be done using geometry nodes, but I don't have the skills at the moment to find/understand how. If anyone wants to share a solution from my case, that would be great !