# How to create additional random object batches on the z-axis using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I learned how to randomly place the objects in the collection and let them be placed only once per object.
[image]
This object was used to prevent the same object from appearing twice.
[image]
Geometry node for this object.
[image]
This is the geometry node of the result.
[image]
This ensures that objects in the next collection are placed randomly and not repeatedly.

I want to know how to arrange this result additionally on the z-axis.

I want to know two ways.

1. How to add it to the z-axis as the result below
2. When the z-axis is arrayed,I want to make them have a different random arrangement than below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approached it as an integer sequence: Took your short random N-digits long sequence and put it several times in a row (see the table row A), then I took the source of random values again (with different seed)  but this time I put each value N-times in a row (B), then I summed it up (Sum) and finally calculated its reminder after division by N. This way I kept the mutual uniqueness but mixed them at the cluster level (Mod).

[image]

The last row when divided to rows by cluster:

[image]

To implement it in GN I used your randomizing object two times (but I actually duplicated it and made seed as a modifier input attribute to improve randomness) and utilized the fact that depending on whether the object is created "As instance" or not, orders points in different manner (actually like A and B in the table). Then it was just a simple arithmetic as described above.

[image]

Randomizing only one row and then copy it is easy and can be made in many ways. I implemented a switch controlled by a modifier attribute. See results for switch on and off bellow:

[image]

[image]

It is not perfect. I am not so good at modular arithmetic to tell how good pseudo-random numbers it provide, but the fact is there are some seeds where it looks suspicious. Actually even your GN randomizing object isn't perfect - it works for given seed (0) just because of pure luck. Actually there is non-zero probability it returns just one vertex. To reduce this probability I recommend to increase the number of generated points to some humongous number.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Thank you for your kind reply and effort.
If I use this method that I learned from the video, there will be a problem when increasing the count, and it happens here, too.
If i add objects to the collection and adjust the count accordingly, there are objects that are repeated, but isn't this method itself not good? 
Is there a way to make this easier and without errors?
If you have any reference materials, please recommend them.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. What video? Did I miss something? I assume you learned that randomizing method from a video. But problem lays apparently there. I just used what you got and applied it to more rows. And no, I don't currently know better method for variating the objects without repeating. I found randomizing in GN rather problematic in general so far. I'll try to think about it once I get some time. Afaik in Blender 3.5 there should be loops, that could solve this easily.

Comment: I found better randomizer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265202/geonodes-mix-position-with-random-index-values-how-to-make-random-values-uniqu 
Works really good. It was even possible to get rid of those helper objects, but It turned out the modulation of individual lines is also a weakness. In this way, it is possible to create as many permutations as there are items on the row. Once there are more rows, the permutations start repeating.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will refer to the data you recommended.
Thank you