# GN: Find Second Nearest Point

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can find a first nearest point. How can I find a second nearest point?

PS: The screenshot is from Blender 3.2. Feel free to use any Blender version.

[image]

Comment: No time to try it, but just an idea: maybe there's a way with the _Delete Geometry_ node... find the nearest, delete it and find the nearest in the reduced geometry... that should be the second nearest. Of course you must somehow preserve the original points and their indices...

Comment: Although depending on how you implement that it could be problematic, because for one point the second nearest might be one first nearest of a different point but then it's gone... maybe there's a way of feeding the distance to nearest into a math node set to greater than and then find the nearest which has a larger distance, that should be second nearest too.

Comment: The only way to do this is sorting: for each point you need to find a list of points sorted by distance to that point - and pick the 2nd. [How can I re-sort the points/indexes of an object in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/264857/60486)

Comment: Personally, I find the two suggestions from *MarkusvonBroady* and *GordonBrinkman* very useful and both should actually work. However, I would prefer the sorting suggested by @MarkusvonBroady.

Comment: After reading through the question again, I realize that we may have all misunderstood you: In order to find the second closest point, we would first have to know from which point you actually want to find the second closest point. Therefore the question: Where is the reference point? Is it variable? Is the starting point always the current point? Please be so kind and explain this a little more precisely. Thank you!

Comment: @quellenform speak for yourself, I understood  in his screenshot for each point coming from "Distribute Points", he is finding the nearest point from "Grid" node, so I'm pretty sure he wants to find 2nd nearest point for each point. Since TA doesn't have an option to find 2nd nearest, you need to remove 1st nearest for it to find the 2nd nearest, but since 1st nearest is potentially different for each point… You would have to duplicate the geometry as many times as many points it has… Very similar to my quadratic sorting, which as I understand is obsolete now.

Comment: **However**, in this special case you can solve it mathematically, because grid vertex positioning is predictable. But I'm not a fan of solving a specific case because the way the question is phrased, future folk looking for a problem will probably look for a solution involving arbitrary geometry.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady OK, then the misunderstanding was definitely mine alone ;-) Anyway, I currently don't have a very good idea how this task could be solved (procedurally & performantly).