# Geometry Nodes: Recreate objects from collection using attributes

Tags: geometry-nodes, collections, custom-attributes

A bunch of differently sized small cubes (referred below as objects 'A') need to be arranged in front of a much larger object (object 'B'). They never touch the object and do not need to line up with each other. Each small cube can be manually repositioned at any time in front of the larger one using its own Geometry Node setup. A hole must be made for each one in object 'B' when in front of it, and the hole always follows the small cubes position whether left/right or up/down. The hole is customised in size for each small cube, but only the small cube 'knows' the size of the hole it wants created for it. The hole size does not necessarily reflect the size of its small cube.

The method being attempted here is to use a bounding box to determine the size of the hole. Objects ‘A’ record attributes relating to vertices of their offset bounding box being its Max. and Min. position. Multiple object ‘A’ are placed in a Collection.

Object ‘B’ refers to this collection. The bounding boxes from each ‘A’ are to be recreated as Cubes from the collection and intersect object ‘B’. Object ‘B’ needs to interact with these new objects separately in a Boolean without any influence from their associated original ‘A’ Geometry.
It appears that only 1 item of the collection is being created:[image]

How can each item in the collection have the new related geometry created? Have tried several similar sounding solutions from other posts but this is as close as I could get.

I understand that only 1 Geometry can be sent to Group Output, hence the attempted workaround.
Thanks.

Comment: you describe your technical issues. Maybe you should explain the animation/graphical result you want to achieve which you might get by a totally different approach....

Comment: Have to agree with Chris.. I find myself trying to reverse-engineer your goal from the method. Could you start your question with a clear statement of what result you're looking for?

Comment: Question has been updated with what I am looking for. It is not an animation.

Comment: The problem definitely is too localized, but it seems it can be rephrased simply as "How do I produce min and max statistical values for a field of multiple groups", i.e. how to implement "group ID" known e.g. from Accumulate Field node to work with Attribute Statistic node. And the answer is you can't, but you can use various tricks to produce a minimum/maximum, e.g. by using raycasting or [sorting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277587/60486).

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do and I've tested something similar some time ago and I just don't think GN was tailored for this kind of setups. It's possible, but you will save yourself a lot of headaches if you just use separate meshes for separate purposes. I think you can benefit from the collections and the boolean modifier collection mode for what you're trying to do.