# How can I give custom index to duplicates inside a simulation zone?

Tags: geometry-nodes, custom-attributes, duplicate

I'm trying to create a simulation for cell division. The idea is pretty simple.

1. Get one point
2. Duplicate the point inside a simulation using the duplicate node
3. Instance a "cell"
4. Move only the "newly" duplicated cells

Solved problems
2. Using *math node* modulo and *switch node* to create cells only at fixed intervals  i.e.) 4 second

[image: duplicate_index]

Unsolved
4. I've tried move the cells using another (or the same?) simulation and selecting the instances using the instance index (and also the points index. The problem is that first of all the duplicate (as expected) have all same index, also I did not succeeded in storing a *custom attribute* and to retrieve the *named attribute*
I tried to store a custom attribute and use this for moving only particles with custom attribute but with no luck.

[image]

EDIT 7/8/2023. It seems it is not possible to change the index inside the nodes. Using instancing worked

Comment: Please edit the question and [share a .blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/)  so that the kind people who might be willing to help you don't have to waste their time recreating the node setup in your image.

Comment: @Chris we have this: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2620/60486 I have it on my todo list to write a guide to ask a good question, but based on my experience, when you point out flaws of the question, its author rarely improves it substantially. The guide needs to be very thorough with examples, but I have my doubts authors will care to read a long guide, yet alone put the effort to apply the advice…

Comment: @Jojostack: ok, if you always adapt your question by new wishes...sorry, then i won't help you anymore. That's not the sense of this site - and that is waste of my time. Good luck.

Comment: @Chris actually I changed the question according to feedback, and by the way you didn't help but just answered something that wasn't asked if you re-read the question at first. My question was very clear.  I want to give custom index to duplicates inside a simulation zone as in the title. And there is a reason for that, but if you wanted to show how to duplicate stuff it's another story.

Comment: @Chris also as you should now I prefer changing the question instead of commenting for this reason. Comments are generally used in order to request clarification, leave constructive criticism, or to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post. They're largely regarded as potentially temporary and liberally deleted when no longer needed. Read more on the purpose of comments and their guidelines

Comment: You can't set an index, but you can sort elements and create new geometry by sampling data from the sorted elements: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/264857/60486

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that it does not seem possible to change the index of the duplicates inside the loop. I've come out with a solution that instead of the duplicate node use a instance to points node. It work as I wanted (also the nodes for duplicating at a fixed step in time work).[image]

there's the link to the scene

[image]

and the nodes
[image]