# Geometry Nodes: How to Generate ID based on order on X axis

Tags: geometry-nodes, splines

I have a curve object with multiple splines. I can loft them, using something like the Higgsas GeoNodes "Loft Splines" node-group. This kind of approach uses the spline Index to determine what order they're lofted together.

Instead, I would like to loft based on the order of the splines on the X axis (ties going to the original spline Index). I can get the mean position of each spline by evaluating Position in the Spline domain (this returns the mean of the points on that spline), giving me a canonical value to use to determine order... I could also use the position of the start or end vertex, or some other position. The problem I'm facing is the re-ordering part.

I'm not sure how to take the values and get this sort of ordering back (Original indexes in blue, new indexes in red)

[image: Lofted curves showing original indexes in blue and new indexes in red]

As you can see, the lofted surface doubles back on itself because the splines were created "out of order", which is not what I want as my result

My last resort is to write a python script to populate an attribute, but I want to avoid that because I'm doing this to practice thinking using functional programming methods in Geometry Nodes. I'm in Blender 3.6.1, so I can do it with Simulation Nodes if that's what's needed, but I'm not good at this thinking yet.

Once I've got the coordinate-based indexes, I can tackle how to change up the lofting node to use them instead of the spline index

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264857/how-can-i-re-sort-the-points-indexes-of-an-object-in-geometry-nodes/264975#264975

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this setup using Blender 4.0 Repeat Zone also you can replicate the same setup using blender 3.6 Simulation node

[image]

Comment: Hi, Higgsas.. just taking a moment to congratulate you on your very practical collection of GN utilities. Ordering profiles along a _path_ may be more general than by X?  (You could always throw in a straight line to do: 'by X'.)  A   'Loft Curves Along Curve' would fill a hole in Blender's modelling tools..

Comment: Oh my goodness I conjured up the expert themselves. Thank you!