# Point Clouds Sorting "Twice"

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a point cloud I want to sort by some attribute (y position).

I also want to sort points by another attribute (a dot product), the end result being that points with a higher dot product value use the points that have a higher y position value.

[image]

Current setup. I want lighter squares to be above darker squares.

Comment: ...maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264857/

Comment: I have a node group that does the native sorting method, and it works fine for both attributes, but I'm having trouble making one affect the other if that makes sense. Like having the index of the point that has the highest "A" value get the index of the point that has the highest "B" value.