# Is it possible to do "Mesh>Sort Elements>Selected" in geometry nodes?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, vertices, geometry, procedural

In Blender there is a function call "Sort Elements", which change indices order (but without changing position of vertices, edges or faces), depending on different variables (for example: "Selected").

Is it possible to recreate this function in geometry nodes, without changing shape of existing geometry?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

## Edit

@e3_productions linked [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264857/how-can-i-re-sort-the-points-indexes-of-an-object-in-geometry-nodes) article in a comment. It indeed answers the question about how to sort the index in geometry nodes. However, it differs significantly from so does the built-in "Sort Elements" function. "Sort Elements" does not change the position of vertices, edges or faces in any way. So i think, that this question should be still open.

Comment: I've done a bit of research and it doens't seem like you can do that in geometry nodes and is only available in edit mode. However, this [Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264857/how-can-i-re-sort-the-points-indexes-of-an-object-in-geometry-nodes) seems similar to what you're asking and might have a possible answer.

Comment: @e3_productions thanks for answer! I read this [Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264857/how-can-i-re-sort-the-points-indexes-of-an-object-in-geometry-nodes), but unfortunately the solutions from this thread are significantly different than what "sort elements" does.

Comment: Alrighty. My bad then. I'll keep looking for you though!

Comment: You cannot re-sort the points of an existing geometry in any case with *Geometry Nodes*. You can only, as seen in the linked answer (and the related examples), create a new geometry and move its points to the original positions. Therefore it is a duplicate.