# Geometry Nodes: How to Find the Index of a point by looking for its attributes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have created two 10 vertex circles using geometry nodes, assigned a random integer of  0-10 for each vertex and stored the respective values as an attribute. Both mesh circle uses a different seed for the random value node. Within each mesh the attributes may have repeating integers, but thats fine.

I am trying to move the points in mesh A to mesh B by grouping them up according to their equal attributes. (EG: Vertices in mesh A where Attribute=7, gets moved to the position of vertex in mesh B where attribute=7 and so on.)

My plan is to obtain the index of the vertices in Mesh B by inputting its attributes, and using the output index to sample its position.I know i can obtain the attributes of a particular point using its index with the Sample index node, but how do i obtain the index of a particular point using its attribute?[image]

[image]

Comment: The thing is several points may end up with the same value, so you're going to have to decide which one of them to snap to. You should be able to do this using sorting (for iterative methods, use the repeat zone in Blender 4.0beta) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264857/how-can-i-re-sort-the-points-indexes-of-an-object-in-geometry-nodes

Comment: What happens if you have multiple 7s in both Meshes A and B?

Comment: tbh i would add your real end goal to your question as well, because maybe someone comes up with a better idea than comparing attributes...which might result in very bad performance