Fixing / moving indexes around curve to fix loft / bridge between curves using geometry nodes
I'm trying to fix a bad loft between 2 curves by resampling and reversing / adjusting the curve indexes but it didn't work.
I have 2 curves:

I'm trying to bridge them to look like this using geometry nodes:

What I get is this:

Node group:

Note: The loft node group was taken from blenderartists.org.


Have you already tried the Sort Elements node?

@quellenform No, I haven't.  I was actually trying to see if i could remap the indexes somehow by rotating the indexes around the curve somehow (but that didn't work)

@quellenform I did look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264857/how-can-i-re-sort-the-points-indexes-of-an-object-in-geometry-nodes  the issue is moving the indexes around to where I want them.  Specifically I looked at https://i.sstatic.net/lGX7ZQ69.png

You can solve this task by converting the curve into points and then back into a curve.
The Curve to Points and Points to Curve nodes help you to do this.
The latter gives you the option of specifying a weight when converting.
In your case, you can simply increase the index by any value and use a Math node set to Wrap type to achieve the shift.
Something like this:

(Blender 4.2.2+)

Here's an adaptive setup that should work in most cases - it rotates indices and flips winding direction to match well, as well as it detects if the normals are god - which will work only if you start with a geometry that has faces, otherwise you could compare normals to relative positions to spline centers...

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Separate Edge Ring

Imgur mirror
Align 0 Indices

Imgur mirror
Do Directions Match?

Imgur mirror
Reverse (pin 0)

Imgur mirror

